# What causes the "screaming" sound from sausages when cooking them?

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, food

I saw this Youtube clip and wondered what's causing the screaming sounds?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Qz_8zxEGho&ab_channel=perhoskoira

Something to do with the cooking oil and how it reacts with the sausage?

Answer (score 9):

The water inside the meat of a sausage being fried turns to steam and wants to expand out of the sausage casing. It finds any hole in the sausage casing that it can, and then squirts out under pressure. The escaping pressurized steam makes the sausage whistle as it cooks in the pan.

Comment: Do I have to come to Ph.SE to hear about whistling sausages? LOL ;-)

Comment: @Gert - See [Camp Fire Crackle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106097/37364)

Comment: @mmesser314 Yeah, not bad either that one...